# JQuery - grab corresponding event of blur-Action

Tags: jquery, validation, events, blur

Hi I have a form and on one input field I set a blur event. A user leaves the input field, I validate it and then I decide if it is okay. If the value of the field is not okay I am alerting an information box. Anyway if the user hits a link to leave the page I cannot stop him. If a link is clicked by the user I have to prevent the default behaviour. How do I recognize by what event user has left the input field? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this  http://api.jquery.com/unload/

As they says in the doc

> The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates
>   away from the page. This could mean one of many things. The user could
>   have clicked on a link to leave the page, or typed in a new URL in the
>   address bar. The forward and back buttons will trigger the event.
>   Closing the browser window will cause the event to be triggered. Even
>   a page reload will first create an unload event.

You can use this event to prevent users from navigating away from the page.

Like this

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert('You have unsaved form values.');
});
```